# Correct Way to do lazy sql writes on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Is there a correct way to do lazy sql writes to a database in iOS if you don't know when your app will be terminated and you need that information? I want to minimize the amount of calls to saveToDatabase while still maintaining all the data I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple recommends saving your data when your [app delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) receives the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` message. If you're targeting pre iOS 4.0 you'll want to do this in the `applicationWillTerminate:` method as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should handle any database operation inside an iOS app, use a php page or something like it to act as a intermediary. Direct accessing db from an iOS app could be a big security issue.

Comment: Any particular reason for voting down? It would be helpful for both me as well if you can explain, rather than just vote.